# The items in listBox do not want to be dragged out

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, drag-and-drop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make drag-and-drop from one list to another in C#/WindowsForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124282/how-to-make-drag-and-drop-from-one-list-to-another-in-c-windowsforms)

I am trying to make 2 listBoxes (with use of WinForms) with ability to drag and drop form one to another but even after setting up the property 'AllowDrop' of the listBoxes to True, the items from one listBox do not want to be dragged out of it - the cursor does not change and none of the DragLeave, DragDrop etc. methods are being called.

Am I missing something ?

please comment if you want me to add some code.

Comment: I think you'll find the answer I got a few days ago quite helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066982/disabling-drag-selection-on-listbox/8067046#8067046

Comment: Post (at least) the MouseDown event code that starts the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call [`DoDragDrop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx) on the source listBox to start the drag operation. This is usually done in response to some criteria event (i.e. mouse click)

Comment: Thanks, I have just figured it out as you posted it :/ I will try to finish what I can and I will edit the question.